# Select Statement Nested Query

Tags: sql-server, zapier

I am using Zapier to add rows to SQL Server tables. However, I have needed to use the find row via custom query and create specific INSERT statements

However, Zapier will only work if there is select statement at the start of the query. The insert works but the flow fails as Zapier can only process one query / statement.

My query is

```
insert into Table_A (EntryID, FirstName)
output inserted.EntryID, inserted.FirstName into Table_B (EntryID, Firstname)
values (102, 'Fred')


select * 
from ILR_Test 
where EntryID = 102
```

Is there a way of making the insert activity part of a select statement through a subquery or some other way.

Thanks

Comment: Inserts and selects require two separate statements AFAIK.

Comment: This is not possible in SQL Server.  Postgres does have such functionality, if changing the database is an option.